# C++ Builder .exe program in other computers

Tags: exe, c++builder

I’m working in a Program for the University using C++Builder 6.

The program works perfectly in my computer, but it doesn’t work in any other computer.
I have already disabled the `PACKAGES->BUILD WITH RUNTIME PACKAGES` and the `LINKER-> USE DYNAMIC RTL` options.

What else can I do?

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.programmingforums.org/thread21196.html

Comment: @daniel You need to specify what type of program you're building. Is it a Win32 GUI? a Console app? a Dll? etc.

Comment: What is the actual problem/error you are experiencing when running the app on other machines?

Answer (score 0):

With these options disabled, you will be able to run your application on any computer, except:

- If you are using a component that requires installing another resource. For instance if you are using SQL, it will run, but obviously it will not use SQL functions if no SQL resource is installed on your computer;
- If the Windows version cannot run it. E.g., you cannot run it on Windows CE, Windows 3.1... except if you compile it to run on these different versions.

Just to optimize your .EXE file, just press the Release button on `Project > Options > Compiler`, so debug data will not be stored on it.